# Deserialize different json property to same model property conditionally

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

Lets say I have the below json.

```
{
   "allitemscount":2,
   "allitems":[
        {"itemid":"1","itemname":"one"}, 
        {"itemid":"2","itemname":"two"}],
   "customitems":[
       {"itemid":"3","itemname":"three"}, 
       {"itemid":"4","itemname":"four"}]
}
```

and when deserializing this json, it should go to the below C# model.

```
public class response
{
  public int allitemscount;
  public List<item> items;
}

public class item
{
   public string itemid;
   public string itemname;
}
```

Question:
How to switch between `allitems` and `customitems` based on a condition? For eg., if `useAllitems` is true, `allitems` from the json to be filled in items and if `useCustomItems` is true, `customitems` to be filled in items property. Please help on how to do this.

Using JsonProperty on `public List<item> items` is allowing to switch between either `allitems`, but is there a way to deserialize based on the above mentioned condition.

Comment: do you get condition from inside of application or from json?

Comment: From application...

Comment: check my answer just pass parameter from the application. it should work clean.

Comment: did you try to implement my answer mate?

Comment: Yeah..it worked like piece of cake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it with writing our own ItemConverter which inherited from JsonConverter,

Sample model json that I use in my trying:

```
{
  "allitemscount": 2,
  "UseCustomItems": true,
  "allitems": [
    {
      "itemid": "1",
      "itemname": "one"
    },
    {
      "itemid": "2",
      "itemname": "two"
    }
  ],
  "customitems": [
    {
      "itemid": "3",
      "itemname": "three"
    },
    {
      "itemid": "4",
      "itemname": "four"
    }
  ]
}
```

Console application's main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"\model.json")) // json path
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();

        var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json, new ItemConverter());
    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class Result // main object
{
    [JsonProperty("allitemscount")]
    public long Allitemscount { get; set; }

    public bool UseCustomItems { get; set; }
}

public class ResultA : Result // CustomItems Model
{
    [JsonProperty("customitems")]
    private List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ResultB : Result // AllItems Model
{
    [JsonProperty("allitems")]
    private List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("itemid")]
    public string Itemid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("itemname")]
    public string Itemname { get; set; }
}
```

And the ItemConverter that we used while deserializing to object:

```
internal class ItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private Type currentType;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Item).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || objectType == typeof(Result);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (item["UseCustomItems"] != null)
        {
            // save the type for later.
            switch (item["UseCustomItems"].Value<bool>())
            {
                case true:
                    currentType = typeof(ResultA);
                    return item.ToObject<ResultA>(); // return result as customitems result
                case false:
                    currentType = typeof(ResultB);
                    return item.ToObject<ResultB>(); // return result as allitems result
            }
            return item.ToObject<Result>();
        }

        // use the last type you read to serialise.
        return item.ToObject(currentType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The result should be like bellowing image
[image]

I hope this solution help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize above json by changing your `response` class as follows,

```
public class response{
      public int allitemscount;
      public List<item> allitems;
      public List<item> customitems;    
}
```

then use the following code,

```
var jsonData = "{\"allitemscount\":2,   \"allitems\":[{\"itemid\":\"1\",\"itemname\":\"one\"}, {\"itemid\":\"2\",\"itemname\":\"two\"}],\"customitems\":[{\"itemid\":\"3\",\"itemname\":\"three\"},{\"itemid\":\"4\",\"itemname\":\"four\"}]}";

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<response>(jsonData);
foreach(var str in data.allitems) {
          Console.WriteLine(str.itemid +'-'+str.itemname);
}
foreach(var str in data.customitems) {
          Console.WriteLine(str.itemid +'-'+str.itemname);
}
```

Comment: Already application is using items collection and do not want to make too many changes by introducing one more collection. I thought the neater solution would be to read customjsondata into the same collection.